# Proper method of converting base64 image strings to binary?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I have a table in a SQLite database that contains about 15,000 single-page document scans stored as base64 strings.  If I understand correctly, converting these to binary would reduce the size of the table by 25%.

Is it correct that it is not possible to convert the images to binary in SQLite directly but the base64 strings need to be converted to images first and then to binary? If so, will creating an image in Tcl from each base64 string and converting to binary suffice? And are there any tricky items that a novice is likely to overlook in attempting to do so?

When the test code below is executed, it appears that `img_binary` is binary data, but is this the correct approach?

Thank you.

```
set db "database_name"
sqlite3 dbws $db
#Base64 strings in database are prefixed with "data:image/gif;charset=utf-8;base64,"
set l [expr {[string length {data:image/gif;charset=utf-8;base64,}] -1}]
dbws eval { select img_base64 from lexi_raw where img_no = $nbr } {
   image create photo ::img::lexi -data [string replace $img_base64 0 $l]
   set img_binary [::img::lexi data -format png]; #Does this return binary to be written to SQLite?
   puts $img_binary
}
```

Comment: If you have stored a base64-encoded GIF in your DB, it is surely sufficient to decode the base64 and store the result which will be a GIF. I don't see why you would need to re-create any images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a built-in base64 decoder, but you can add one.

Try this:

```
package require sqlite3
sqlite3 db :memory:
db function base64decode -argcount 1 -deterministic -returntype blob {binary decode base64}
db eval {SELECT base64decode('SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxk') AS message}
```

The trick is the `function` method, which creates a new function (called `base64decode`) that is implemented by the given Tcl script fragment (`binary decode base64`; the argument is appended as a word to that). I'm passing `-argcount 1` because we only ever want to pass a single argument here, `-deterministic` because the result is always the same for the same input, and `-returntype blob` because we know the result is binary.

If you want to do more complex processing (such as stripping a prefix as well) then it's best to implement by calling a procedure:

```
db function base64decode -argcount 1 -deterministic -returntype blob myDecoder
proc myDecoder value {
    # Strip a leading prefix
    regsub {^data:image/gif;charset=utf-8;base64,} $value "" value
    # Decode the rest
    return [binary decode base64 $value]
}
```

Comment: Fascinating! I am not a big user of `sqlite` or `tcl`, so could you please explain briefly (or give a link) showing what you do with this `package require`-thing when building (?) compiling (?) installing (?) Tcl/sqlite or something please? Many thanks.

Comment: Also, still not a big user of `sqlite`, I think that a base64 representation of an image in `sqlite` might be stored as some kind of string type, whereas a binary GIF image, probably needs to be stored as some kind of BLOB (doesn't it?) so the field type might need to change... maybe?

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was certainly approaching it the hard way.  Thanks again for all you help on my several recent questions.  Tcl and SQLite, when one knows what one is doing, make it easy to accomplish much.